# SQL server search date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the SQL Server, do I have to specify the timestamp when searching date range ? for example, these two queries will return same results.

```
SELECT SalesOrderID,   ShipDate
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
WHERE ShipDate BETWEEN '2005-07-23T00:00:00' AND '2005-07-24T23:59:59';
```

and

```
SELECT SalesOrderID,   ShipDate
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
WHERE ShipDate BETWEEN '2005-07-23' AND '2005-07-24';
```

Answer (score 3):

`BETWEEN` is inclusive, and the default time when none is specified is 00:00:00.

So if you exclude the time portion and your field is a `DATETIME` you'll exclude any records after time 00:00:00 on the *ending day*.  If your field is of type `DATE` then the time is not necessary.

You can also just use `<` and a day later:

```
WHERE ShipDate >= '2005-07-23' 
   AND ShipDate < '2005-07-25'
```

Comment: if I update a record to '2005-07-23 10:00:00.000', still can get that record out.

Comment: Yes, but if it was `2005-07-24 10:00:00.000` it would be excluded as that's after `2005-07-24 00:00:00.000`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT SalesOrderID,   ShipDate
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
WHERE cast(ShipDate as date) BETWEEN cast('20050723' as date) AND cast('20050724' as date);
```

when cast to date type, you dont need write hour, minutes... :)

Comment: This approach has some problems. See [Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34047/3690)